# ГО в предложении

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Выделите грамматическую основу в следующем предложении: Припаркованных автомобилей были считаные единицы.

Comment: Задания сюда не выкладываете!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что д/з.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение непростое по грамматике, лингвисты по-разному определяют подобные предложения с количественной оценкой: двусоставное с простым глагольным сказуемым,  или безличное (количественно-бытийное), или назывное. К примеру, грамматически различаются предложения "машин было/собралось много", "машин много", "много машин".

Кроме того,  здесь количество задается фразеологическим сочетанием "считанные единицы", соответственно, встает вопрос о согласовании подлежащего и сказуемого по числу.

Проще остановиться  **на форме двусоставного предложения**: были (сказуемое) считанные единицы  автомобилей (подлежащее).

Сравнить: Припаркованных автомобилей  было пять. Было (сказуемое) пять автомобилей (подлежащее).

Примеры:

Словом, фронтовиков в соединении **оказалось** считанные единицы.Однако казненных **были** считанные единицы.  На тогдашнем унылом телевидении подобных программ **были** считанные единицы,